# Ruby - Stripe: Missing required param: type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a bank account using Ruby stripe API. but it gives the stripe error "Missing required param: type".

I am using following ruby code:

```
account = Stripe::Account.create({
    :country => 'US',
    :managed => true,
    :transfer_schedule => {
        :interval => 'weekly',
        :weekly_anchor => 'friday'
    },
    :legal_entity => {
        :dob => {
            :day => birthday.day,
            :month => birthday.month,
            :year => birthday.year
        },
        :first_name => first_name,
        :last_name => last_name,
        :type => 'individual'
    },
    :tos_acceptance => {
        :date => Time.now.to_i,
        :ip => request.remote_ip
    }
})
```

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/JagdeepSingh/166fa03829275cb6131d77abc6d4c148#custom-accounts

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the proper parameters to the API.

Please check this document for the proper request and response returned by Stripe.

https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#create_account

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_bcd1234"

Stripe::Account.create(
  :type => 'standard',
  :country => 'US',
  :email => 'bob@example.com'
)
```

To point out you are not passing `:type` param in the outer hash. You need to move it to the first level.

```
account = Stripe::Account.create(
  {
    :country => 'US',
    :managed => true,
    :type => 'individual', # Move this from nested to first level 
    :transfer_schedule => {
      :interval => 'weekly',
      :weekly_anchor => 'friday'
    },
    :legal_entity => {
      :dob => {
        :day => birthday.day,
        :month => birthday.month,
        :year => birthday.year
      },
      :first_name => first_name,
      :last_name => last_name
    },
    :tos_acceptance => {
      :date => Time.now.to_i,
      :ip => request.remote_ip
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: It's giving me another below error
"Invalid type: must be one of standard, express, or custom"

Comment: That's because you are passing the value of :type as 'individual'

Comment: Pass whichever is appropriate from `standard`, `express`, or `custom`

Comment: And please check the documentation you will get solution for almost everything there itself